# $f \mapsto b, b(r,m)=r\cdot f(m)$ gives an isomorphism of $R$-modules $\Phi_N : \text {Hom}_R(M,N) \rightarrow \text {Bilin}_R(R×M,N)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, bilinear-form, module-isomorphism

Let $R$ be a commutative ring $M$ and $N$:  $R$-modules Let  $f : M \rightarrow N$ is a homomorphism,

I have shown that the map $b: R\times M \rightarrow N$ given by $b(r,m) = r \cdot f(m)$ is R-bilinear. I am trying to show that

$f \mapsto b$ gives an isomorphism of $R$-modules
$\Phi_N : \text {Hom}_R(M,N) \rightarrow  \text {Bilin}_R(R×M,N)$

**Injectivity:**  Let $f_1,f_2\in  \text {Hom}_R(M,N)$

$\Phi(f_1)=\Phi(f_2)\implies b_1=b_2$ whith $b_1(r,m)=rf_1(m)$ and $b_2(r,m)=rf_2(m)$

then $rf_1(m)=rf_2(m) \forall m \in M$.. How do I conclude that $f_1=f_2$ ? In a commutative ring elements are not  necessarily invertible , so would it suffice to take $r=1$ to get rid of that r and conclude injectivity ?

**surjectivity:** Let $b \in \text {Bilin}_R(R×M,N)$  I need to find an $f\in  \text {Hom}_R(M,N)$  s.t. $\Phi_N(f)=b$, how do I do that? I am stuck here. Any help is welcome

Comment: For injectivity, yes you can take $r=1$ since the identity holds for all $r$ in the (presumably unital) ring $R$. For surjectivity, consider $f$ defined by $f(m)=b(1,m)$.

Comment: @blargoner why can you do that? For example, what if $r$ is in the annihilator of $\text{Hom}_R(M, N)$? Then we would have $rf_1(m) = 0 = rf_2(m)$, but not necessarily $f_1=f_2$.

Comment: For surjectivity, since $f$ is an $R$-mod homomorphism, $b(r, m) = rf(m) = f(rm)\in \text{im}(f)$.

Comment: @IAAW There's no question of what if because you *choose* $r=1$ and let $m$ vary.

Comment: But then aren't you just proving that $b_1(1, -) = b_2(1, -) \Rightarrow f_1 = f_2$?

Comment: @IAAW If $b_i=\Phi_N(f_i)$, then $b_1(1,-)=f_1$ and $b_2(1,-)=f_2$, and certainly if $b_1=b_2$ then $b_1(1,-)=b_2(1,-)$.

Comment: Omg, I feel dumb, you're right.